# Download a file part by part in Python 3

Tags: python, memory, urllib, packet, download

I'm using Python 3 to download a file:

```
local_file = open(file_name, "w" + file_mode)
local_file.write(f.read())
local_file.close()
```

This code works, but it copies the whole file into memory first. This is a problem with very big files because my program becomes memory hungry. (Going from 17M memory to 240M memory for a 200 MB file)

I would like to know if there is a way in Python to download a small part of a file (packet), write it to file, erase it from memory, and keep repeating the process until the file is completely downloaded.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lazy Method for Reading Big File in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519633/lazy-method-for-reading-big-file-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the method described here:

[Lazy Method for Reading Big File in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519633/lazy-method-for-reading-big-file-in-python)

I am specifically referring to the accepted answer.  Let me also copy it here to ensure complete clarity of response.

```
    def read_in_chunks(file_object, chunk_size=1024):
        """Lazy function (generator) to read a file piece by piece.
        Default chunk size: 1k."""
        while True:
            data = file_object.read(chunk_size)
            if not data:
                break
            yield data


    f = open('really_big_file.dat')
    for piece in read_in_chunks(f):
        process_data(piece)
```

This will likely be adaptable to your needs:  it reads the file in smaller chunks, allowing for processing without filling your entire memory.  Come back if you have any further questions.

Comment: What method are you even referring to?

Comment: The one that I linked to, which I will link here again: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519633/lazy-method-for-reading-big-file-in-python)

Comment: You just linked to the question. Which of the answers is the method you're suggesting?

Comment: I assumed it was clear that I was referring to the accepted answer.  I will edit my post to clarify further.

Comment: The accepted answer isn't atomic and can change after you point vaguely in its direction